# Как распознать нажатие и удержание или не удержание клавиши, keyboard

Tags: python, python-keyboard

Всем доброго времени суток, делаю приложение, в котором нужно обрабатывать при нажатии клавиши caps lock, удерживается ли она или нет, код должен отключать caps lock если она была нажата, но не удержана и оставлять, если она нажата и удержана 1сек, выходит наоборот, менять местами действия пробовал, тогда все перестаёт работать, вот код:

```
import time
from time import sleep

while True:
    def print_pressed_keys(e):
        if e.name == 'caps lock' and e.event_type == 'down':
            
            sleep(1)
            if e.name == 'caps lock' and e.event_type == 'down':

                 c = 100
            else:
                keyboard.write('caps lock')
            
                


    keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
    keyboard.wait()
```